# Java String Mutability - java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: offset

Tags: java, string, immutability, field, nosuchfieldexception

I'm new to Java and I saw a Q&A section [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/) with two examples where mutability is removed. Upon testing [MutableString.java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/MutableString.java.html):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field; 

public class MutableString {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String s = "Immutable"; 
        String t = "Notreally"; 

        mutate(s, t);
        StdOut.println(t); 

        // strings are interned so this doesn't even print "Immutable" (!)
        StdOut.println("Immutable");
    } 

    // change the first min(|s|, |t|) characters of s to t
    public static void mutate(String s, String t) {
        try {
            Field val = String.class.getDeclaredField("value"); 
            Field off = String.class.getDeclaredField("offset"); 
            val.setAccessible(true); 
            off.setAccessible(true); 
            int offset   = off.getInt(s); 
            char[] value = (char[]) val.get(s); 
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s.length(), t.length()); i++)
                value[offset + i] = t.charAt(i); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    } 

}
```

I received the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: offset
```

Any input on the following would be greatly appreciated:

> a) why do I get this exception
>      b) how do I check which fields exist in a class (Java strings specifically)

Comment: There is no field `offset` in the class `String`...

Comment: That is such a disgusting way to do things -.-

Comment: @LaurentG: there used to be one in Java 6 (or at least in the Oracle/Sun/OpenJDK implementation). Of course it was never documented, so depending on it was obviously a bug.

Comment: hey @ofer.sheffer are you alive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: these kinds of hacks are interesting lessons in learning and fun trivia. But they are **definitely** not something that you want to use in *any* production code. It *will* lead to pain.

By their very nature, such a hack always depends on implementation details of the classes that are hacked.

In your case you seem to be using a `String` implementation that doesn't have an `offset` field, but uses some other mechanism (or maybe just a different name!).

For example, I've just reviewed the Oracle Java 7 String class and it no longer has the `offset` field (which was used in Java 6 and earlier to share the `char[]` among substrings)!<sup>*</sup>

You can use `Class.getDeclaredFields()` to check which fields this implementation *does* define:

```
for (Field f : String.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
  System.out.println(f);
}
```

For a version of that hack that works with Java 7, you could do this:

```
public static void mutate(String s, String t) {
    try {
        Field val = String.class.getDeclaredField("value"); 
        val.setAccessible(true); 
        char[] value = (char[]) val.get(s); 
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s.length(), t.length()); i++)
            value[i] = t.charAt(i); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Of course, this too will break if the internals of `String` change again.

<sup>* [Here's an Email](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html) that talks about that change, it seems that the sharing of the `char[]` only lead to improved performance in a few, special cases.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I also got my starters +15 reputation so I can finally upvote good responses.